# CheckBox in ListView - Unable to select CheckBox

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, android-checkbox

I have a `ListView` with a `onItemClickListener` attached.
Inside that `ListView` I have some rows, each with a `CheckBox`.

The problem is: when I click the `CheckBox` the `Listener` who answer is the `onItemClickListener` attached to the list. Instead I want the `onCheckedChagedListener` attached to the `CheckBox` to answer.

I've tried to put

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

on root item or my row layout, I've also tried to use the variants `afterDescendants` and `beforeDescendants`, but none of them help me achieve what I want.

I also went through some answers on Stackoverflow and elsewhere but I can't get rid of it...

How can I be able to have both listeners, one on `CheckBox` only and one on whole row?

Comment: where you set listener for `CheckBox`? have you tried to set `onCheckedChangeListener` inside of `onItemClick`? if no, I suggest you to try, because in my case worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, should help.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id){
    CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.cbxList);
    cbx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){

        }
   });
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it doesn't work: neither the CheckBox nor the whole row now respond to the click event.

Comment: previously you said that `onItemClickListener` responds... so does it? Anyways, for more particular problem solving need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

your `checkbox` shouldn't get whole of row and you should set `android:focusable="false"`  to your `checkbox` and in your Adapter you should set `OnCheckedChangeListener` to your `checkbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Add these both **android:clickable & android:focusable** and set them to false.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:clickable="false"        
    android:focusable="false" 

    >
</CheckBox>
```